# Angular controller on DOm that changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, smart-wizard

First of all, I'm using [jQuery-Smart-Wizard](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard).

When I put it into my code:

```
$('#wizard_verticle').smartWizard({
    transitionEffect: 'slide'
});
```

this is supposed to change the DOM, but it's wrapped inside angular controller and it doesn't seems to work for some reason.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4y5azfsm/3/) to reproduce this.

**Errors:**

[image]

Comment: Needs to be initialized in a directive. DOM code doesn't belong in controllers. Doing it in directive assures that element exists when code is run

Comment: this is my first attempt at using angular in my project can you direct me to an example of what you are saying ? @charlietfl

Comment: Ultra simple demo http://plnkr.co/edit/gVQbDo4dPWAYOdaqecJR?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl i think this worked great but can you bind to controller function from directive? example there is a  onFinish: event you can wire when you $('#wizard').smartWizard({ onFinish: gotoSubmit() })  how can this be done?

Comment: see `scope` argument of `link` in demo. Find some tutorials on directives. They are important part of using angular. Also read up on scope inheritance